# Bigquery year-over-year join

Tags: join, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I built a query with a join to layer on yoy data. As soon as I add more dimensions the yoy total doesn't match anymore. Am I applying the using function properly?

When I added browser or device the total is different

````
   (SELECT

 date,
 py_date,
 browser,
 device,
 sum(ga_sessions) as visit,

 FROM (SELECT

 device.browser as browser,
 device.deviceCategory as device,
 PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) as date,
 DATE_SUB(PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date), INTERVAL 364 DAY) as py_date,
 totals.visits as ga_sessions,

 FROM `xx.ga_sessions_20210824`
GROUP BY date, py_date, browser, device
),

 PREV_YEAR as (SELECT

 py_date,
 browser,
 device,
 sum(py_ga_sessions) as py_visit,

 FROM ( SELECT
 PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date) as py_date,
 totals.visits as py_ga_sessions,
 device.browser as browser,
 device.deviceCategory as device

 FROM `xx.ga_sessions_20200824`
 GROUP BY py_date, browser, device
),

DATAPULL as (SELECT *
FROM CURRENT_PERIOD LEFT OUTER JOIN PREV_YEAR USING(py_date, browser, device) ORDER BY date DESC
)

SELECT * FROM DATAPULL```
````

Comment: I'd suggest to remove your project_id and the dataset_id. 

Regarding your issue, you are not selecting the prev_year. The FROM statement should change. Please, take a look at this cookbook that will help you to understand how to query last year and so on: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4419694?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: Good call totally missed that ;) I actually figured it out. I went with a full join instead of just a left. Also joined by date and py_date.